# Unable to understand why the error is occurring

Tags: python, django, excel, excel-formula, openpyxl

I have been trying to concatenate two strings and assign them to a cell in an excel sheet. I am however unable to understand why the below-shown error is occurring as I cannot find any error in the functioning of the rest of the code

the error shown is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AdvaitSNambiar\Desktop\Myfolder\SUTT task\Final\task1test-2-final.py", line 63, in <module>
    ws['D' + str(i) ].value = ws['D' + str(i)].value + '+ EEE'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

```
if (h2 == 'A3'):
                ws['D' + str(i) ].value = ws['D' + str(i)].value + '+ EEE'
```

this was the concatenation I tried to perform

my code is given below

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('names.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
i = 0

while(i<24):
    i = 2
    while(i<24):
        idnum = ws['A' + str(i)]
        idnum1 = idnum.value
        idnum2 = idnum1[4:8]
        if (idnum2 == 'AAPS'):
            ws['D' + str(i)] = 'ECE'
        if (idnum2 == 'ABPS'):
            ws['D' + str(i) ] = 'Manu'
        if (idnum2 == 'A1PS'):
            ws['D' + str(i)] = 'chemical'
        if (idnum2 == 'A2PS'):
            ws['D' + str(i) ] = 'civil'
        if (idnum2 == 'A3PS'):
            ws['D' + str(i) ] = 'EEE'
        if (idnum2 == 'A4PS'):
            ws['D' + str(i)] = 'Mech'
        if (idnum2 == 'A5PS'):
            ws['D' + str(i) ] = 'pharma'
        if (idnum2 == 'A7PS'):
            ws['D' + str(i) ] = 'CSE'
        if (idnum2 == 'A8PS'):
            ws['D' + str(i) ] = 'ENI'
        if (idnum2 == 'B1PS'):
            ws['D' + str(i) ] = 'MSc Bio'
        if (idnum2 == 'B2PS'):
            ws['D' + str(i) ] = 'MSc Chem'
        if (idnum2 == 'B3PS'):
            ws['D' + str(i) ] = 'MSc Eco'
        if (idnum2 == 'B4PS'):
            ws['D' + str(i) ] = 'MSc Math'
        if (idnum2 == 'B5PS'):
            ws['D' + str(i) ] = 'MSc Physics'
        if (idnum2[-2:] != 'PS'):
            h1=idnum2[0:3]
            h2=idnum2[-2:]
            if (h1 == 'B1'):
                ws['D' + str(i) ].value = 'MSc Bio'
            if (h1 == 'B2'):
                ws['D' + str(i) ].value = 'MSc Chem'
            if (h1 == 'B3'):
                ws['D' + str(i) ].value = 'MSc Eco'
            if (h1 == 'B4'):
                ws['D' + str(i) ].value = 'MSc Math'
            if (h1 == 'B5'):
                ws['D' + str(i) ].value = 'MSc Physics'
            if (h2 == 'AA'):
                ws['D' + str(i)].value  = ws['D' + str(i)].value + '+ ECE'
            if (h2 == 'AB'):
                ws['D' + str(i) ].value = ws['D' + str(i)].value + '+ Manu'
            if (h2 == 'A1'):
                ws['D' + str(i)].value  = ws['D' + str(i)].value + '+ chemical'
            if (h2 == 'A2'):
                ws['D' + str(i) ].value = ws['D' + str(i)].value + '+ civil'
            if (h2 == 'A3'):
                ws['D' + str(i) ].value = ws['D' + str(i)].value + '+ EEE'
            if (h2 == 'A4'):
                ws['D' + str(i)].value  = ws['D' + str(i)].value + '+ Mech'
            if (h2 == 'A7'):
                ws['D' + str(i) ].value = ws['D' + str(i)].value + '+ CSE'
            if (h2 == 'A8'):
                ws['D' + str(i) ].value = ws['D' + str(i)].value + '+ ENI'
        i=i+1
            
       

j = 2
while(j<24):
    idnum3 = ws['A' + str(j)]
    idnum4 = idnum3.value
    idnum5 = idnum4[8:12]
    ws['E' + str(j)] = 'f2022' +idnum4+ '@pilani.bits-pilani.ac.in'
    j=j+1

wb.save('names.xlsx')

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('names.xlsx')

print(df1)

excel_data = pd.read_excel('names.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')

json_str = excel_data.to_json(orient='records')

print('Excel Sheet to JSON:\n', json_str)
```

Comment: you cannot use the same variable `i` in two nested loops. use another variable like `j`. Otherwise the outer loop will never finish since you are initializing `i=2` inside.

Comment: You could avoid a lot of duplicated code and make it cleaner by using a Dictionary with elements along the lines of `'AAPS': 'ECE'` and then the if statements all disappear as you can just pick up the modification from the Dictionary.